# Lite weight extensions or plugins for displaying crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I am new to crystal reports, during execution of my project  I'm  not able to see the reports on screen. Its displaying an empty page.

I have already install Run time crystal report `version=13.0.10.1385` of  size 200 MB (from this URL "http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824") but still cant able to see reports. please help me and i also  need any lite weight plugins or extension of size  < 5 MB if available free

Comment: Please post the UI code, and code behind snippet